# Help and Improvement Queue - Edit screen different

Tags: discussion, edits, help-improvement

If I edit a question normally, the edit screen has four boxes:

- Title
- Body
- Tags
- Edit Summary

If I edit a question using the "Edit" button in the H&I Queue, it also has four boxes:

- Body
- Title
- Tags
- **Leave a Comment**

I am so used to editing with the first editor, that I just instinctively left the edit summary in the "leave a comment" box by mistake - and it's only later that I realised that this actually leaves a comment on the question/answer.

So, I have two questions really:

1. How can I leave an edit summary? (or what is put in the edit summary by default instead of anything I write?)
2. Why are the two screens different (it's not just the edit summary thing - the title and body are also the other way around)

Comment: Was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57585181/revisions) the post you're referring to? If so, you may notice that your comment *was* put as the edit summary, it's just commented as well, so do what you did and delete the comment left on the post afterwards.

Comment: ah ok, that answers the first question - thanks